# JavaFX UI third-party components

Tags: user-interface, javafx, components

Do anybody know JavaFX UI components library like DevExpress for .NET? I try to rewrite my .NET app by using JavaFX, but in .NET app I using DevExpress. I like DevExpress for its good-looking anf rich interface and I want to find something similar.

Comment: It there any control in particular that you are looking for ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Yes. I am interested in the analogue of JavaFX's TableView

Comment: @ItachiUchiha The analogue of TableView in DevExpress is DataGrid.

Comment: So use `TableView` :)

Comment: Take a look on [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) and its [features](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/). But it is _only_ a small set of usefull widgets.